# Escaping quotes-are there other characters that can be used?

Tags: javascript, quotes

I understand escaping quotes etc. for javascript.  Are there any other characters that can be used to encase the whole thing rather than just " or '?  Both characters will come up in my piece of text and I don't want to have to put a / before each instance

So, instead of:

```
("Some text where he said "I like this, she say's")
```

something like this(although I'm not expecting the percentage sign to be used)

```
(%Some text where he said "I like this, she say's%
```

Hope that makes a bit of sense!  Thank you.

Comment: Luckily, the apostrophe in “she say's” is a grammatical error which should be omitted, allowing you to use normal single quotes for your string!

Comment: Well, in a total mind blank, I couldn't think of a word that needed an apostrophe!  So I had to plump for that!

Answer (score 1):

Literal strings need to be declared with either `"` or `'`. And within such a declaration, the quotes that surround the string value need to be escaped. So:

```
"Some text where he said \"I like this, she say's"
'Some text where he said "I like this, she say\'s'
```

Both will be interpreted as:

```
Some text where he said "I like this, she say's
```

Comment: It's OK to always escape either quote, regardless of the quotes used to surround the string constant. That makes the writing of server-side "escapeJS" functions a little easier.

Answer (score 0):

No. Only `"` and `'` are valid string delimiters. You have to escape them either as

```
"...\"...'...";
'..."...\'...';
```

(As a cheat, you can put the string in a hidden `<div>` and read the textContent in JS.)

(As another cheat, `/Some text where he said "I like this, she say's/.source`.)

Comment: Oooh, I like that second cheat.  Thanks!

Comment: For the first cheat, however, you'd need to HTML-escape the string first.

Comment: The second one didn't seem to work unless I'm doing something stupid?!

Comment: Hmmm...OK, got to go out now for a bit, but will have a go again later this afternoon.  It was probably me doing something wrong!  Thank you!

Comment: No, still can't get it to work.  How does it know that the slashes at the beginning and the end are the ones to take regard of rather than the other ones in the html?  Thanks.

Comment: @James: The 1st and 2nd "cheat" are mutually exclusive. Use the 2nd like `var xyz = /blah "blah" 'blah'/.source;`. Not that I recommend it.

Comment: Nope, still can't get it to work, which is annoying.  Oh well!

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with content that comes from your server-side template language, you may also have to worry about encoding multi-byte sequences and "control" characters.